# How to export only last changes from SVN repository?

Tags: windows, svn, command-line, windows-xp

I want to export only changes  (files and folders - tree) between HEAD and PREVIOUS revisions using svn export command. Is it possible? How to do it under Windows (command-line)?

Comment: "svn export" exports a tree but you're asking for the "changes between" or "svn diff".  Which is it?

Comment: not svn diff, I want the same result as svn export gives (so it's tree), but including only those elements that have changed in HEAD in comparison to PREV revision.

Comment: Do you want to export files deleted from PREV, so no longer present in HEAD?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
svn diff -rPREV:HEAD --summarize
```

Will give you a list of files modified. You should be able to iterate over the list with whatever scripting languages you have available and create the necessary directories followed by `svn cat` commands to get the contents of each file.

This would be quite easy in bash, maybe someone else can tell you where to go from here in Windows.

Comment: So there is no way to do the job using just svn? That's what I wanted to know.